# regex match coordinates

Tags: javascript, regex, coordinates

From string liike this 
"42.901189372459974,71.36591345071793";
i try to get numbers 42.901189 71.365913

```
            var crds ="42.901189372459974,71.36591345071793";
            var expr = new RegExp("[0-9][0-9]\.[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]","gim");
            var matchedstr = crds.match(expr);
```

and in result i recevied 3 numbers  42.901189 ,372459,71.36591
but for me i need only 2

Comment: [`crds.split(',').map(cord => cord.substring(0, 9));`](https://jsfiddle.net/raggysvb/)

Comment: Where i can read about "cord" ?I don't know what is this)

Comment: `cord` here is the element of array which you get after split. See [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape `\` when using `RegExp` constructor

```
var expr = new RegExp("[0-9][0-9]\\.[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]","gim");
```

But there is no need to use it in this case.

```
var expr = /\d{2}\.\d{6}/gim; // the same as above
```

Comment: Longitudes range from -180 to 180. Be careful with matching only 2 digits before the decimal point.

Comment: @SultanZhumatayev As @Stoyan said `split` might be a better option here.

Comment: And could you help me for this                


    var crds ="53°17'8\"N   69°22'19\"E";
                    var expr1 =new RegExp("[0-9][0-9]°[0-9]?[0-9](\′|\')[0-9]?[0-9]?\.?[0-9]?[0-9](\″|\")[A-Za-z]","gim");
                    var matchedstr = crds.match(expr1);

Comment: `var expr = /\d{1,2}°\d{1,2}'\d{1,2}"[NSWE]/gim`